# truncated svd on tf idf gives value error array is too big

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn, scikits

I am trying to apply TruncatedSVD.fit_transform() on sparse matrix given by TfidfVectorizer in scikit-learn which gives :

```
    tsv = TruncatedSVD(n_components=10000,algorithm='randomized',n_iterations=5)
    tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,max_features=None,strip_accents='unicode',analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',ngram_range=(1, 2), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1)
    tfv.fit(text)
    text = tfv.transform(text)
    tsv.fit(text)

Value error : array is too big
```

What are the other approaches which I can use or dimensionality reduction.

Comment: So how big *is* your data?

Comment: 77946X45906 sparse matrix of type numpy.float64 with 1062178 stored elements.

Comment: Then please post the full traceback. It's hard to see where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the problem is:

```
tsv = TruncatedSVD(n_components=10000...
```

You have 10000 components in your SVD. If you have an m x n data matrix, SVD will have matrices with dimensions m x n_components and n_components x n, and these will be dense, even if the data was sparse. Those matrices are probably too big.

I copied your code and ran it on Kaggle Hashtag data(which is what I think this is from), and at 300 components, python was using up to 1GB. At 10000, you'd use about 30 times that.

Incidentally, what you are doing here is latent semantic analysis, and that isn't likely to benefit from this many components. Somewhere in the range of 50-300 should capture everything that matters.

Comment: Thanks. This saved my life, Indeed 250 components were capturing 99.86% variance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you are getting this error as you are using 32 bit python. Try switching to 64 bit. The other approach for dimensionality reduction for sparse matrices is using `RandomizedPCA` which is PCA using randomized SVD.

Comment: my ubuntu is 32-bit , I don't think it will support 64-bit python. Will try RandomizedPCA

Comment: Randomized PCA also gives array too big, actually my sparse matrix is more than 50000 columns and similar rows returned by TfidfVectorizer .

Comment: `RandomizedPCA` is exactly the same algo as `TruncatedSVD` on sparse matrices (randomized SVD).

Comment: @user595169 I have used truncatedsvd on data larger than 50k columns and similar rows and it works fine.

Comment: Even I am surprised why I am getting this unusual error , what I did is simple. Please see above steps to see if there is any problem in the code.